# Change original price in cart for WooCommerce product variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I tried using this to change the original price in the cart but no dice. I think it's not working because the product I'm using is a variable product. The Product ID is 141 and the variation ID 142.

```
function sv_change_product_price_cart( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( 142 === $cart_item['product_id'] ) {
        $price = '$50.00 per Unit<br>(7-8 skewers per Unit)';
    }
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'sv_change_product_price_cart', 10, 3 );
```

How to make it work

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should need to replace `$cart_item['product_id']` by **`$cart_item['variation_id']`** to make it working for a product variation in your condition.

This function will only change the display, but not the calculation:

```
// Changing the displayed price (with custom label)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'sv_display_product_price_cart', 10, 3 );
function sv_display_product_price_cart( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( 142 == $cart_item['variation_id'] ) {
        // Displaying price with label
        $price = '$50.00 per Unit<br>(7-8 skewers per Unit)';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Here is the hooked function that will change the cart calculation with your price:

```
// Changing the price (for cart calculation)
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'sv_change_product_price_cart', 10, 1 );
function sv_change_product_price_cart( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( 142 == $cart_item['variation_id'] ){
            // Set your price
            $price = 50;

            // WooCommerce versions compatibility
            if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) {
                $cart_item['data']->price = $price; // Before WC 3.0
            } else {
                $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price ); // WC 3.0+
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

So you will get that:

[image]

This code is tested ad works on Woocommerce version 2.6.x and 3.0+